# How to I check if last modification date of a file is equal or bigger than five minutes ago?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to check if a file was modified in the last five minutes and then execute some code.

What I have right now is this code example I'm working on. It's getting there but I can't execute it because

```
  File "c:\Users\CatarinaRibeiro\Desktop\from datetime import date.py", line 8, in <module>
    modificationTime = datetime.datetime(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(configFilePath))))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I know it's because of the data types. I can't figure out other ways to make this work. Do you have any ideas?

```
from datetime import date
import datetime
import os
import time

configFilePath = "C:\\Users\\CatarinaRibeiro\\Pictures\\2.png"

modificationTime = datetime.datetime(time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(configFilePath))))
print("Last modification date") 
print(modificationTime)


today = datetime.datetime.now() 
print("Today")
print(today)
TimeRange = (today) - (datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))
print(TimeRange)
Validation = (modificationTime >= str(TimeRange))


if not Validation:
    print("No new updates on the configuration file")
    print(Validation)

else:
    print("UPDATED")
    print(Validation)
```

Comment: what line is giving the error?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Just added the traceback of the error

Comment: Don't test booleans using constructs such as `if condition == "False":`. Instead use `if condition:` or `if not condition:`

Comment: ok... made that change

Comment: You try to create a "datetime" object from a formatted timestamp string returned by "strftime". This is neither supported in this way nor necessary.

Comment: The biggest issue here is that you are taking perfectly good datetime objects, which are inherently comparable, and converting them to strings and then comparing the strings. Just compare the datetime objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 8 with

```
modificationTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(os.path.getmtime(configFilePath)))
```